# Shell Script for Sauce Connect proxy

Tags: linux, shell, saucelabs

I have created below shell script and running using crontab. This shell script creates a proxy/tunnel in Saucelabs. After adding the shell script to cronjob it's not running, and the proxy/tunnel is not getting created in Saucelabs. The shell script is working as expected when executed manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /SauceLABS/sc-4.8.1-linux/bin/
./sc -u <usernmae> -k <passowrd > --tunnel-pool --region eu-central -T -B all  --tunnel-name Saucelabs_Tunnel -s &
sleep 30
echo "Sauce-Connect is up and running"
```

Comment: `cron` runs in a context where you will not be able to access the tunnel it creates from your interactive session. It works as such, but does not do what you want, or indeed anything useful.

Comment: the cronjob will not create tunnel/proxy? Please clarify here?

Comment: Your interactive shell does not have access to the tunnel which is created in a different session.

Comment: cron job will not work for my use case? Could you please clarify me?